How Do You Execute If-Then Logic On All The Columns Of An xts object in R
I have an xts object with multiple columns in R and I want to convert all the numbers larger than, say, 0.05 to NA (or -99 or something like that).
To get some data to execute on please do the following.
library(purrr); library(quantmod)

GetMySymbols <- function(x) { 
   getSymbols(x, src="yahoo", from='2023-06-01', to='2024-04-01', auto.assign=FALSE)
}
tickers <- c('AAPL','BAC','MSFT','GOOGL','SWKS')
Prices <- map(tickers, GetMySymbols)
Prices <- Prices %>% map(Ad) %> %reduce(merge.xts)
names(Prices) <- tickers
Returns <- diff(Prices, 1, arith=FALSE)-1
#Returns
Max90 <- rollmax(Returns, 90)
Max90 <- na.omit(Max90)

So now I want to adjust any value larger than 0.05 to NA for all the five columns of the object Max90.  I have been googling for a number of hours but I think that this is so simple that there is not a good example out there.
Help would be much appreciated.
I tried a number of hacks of example code out on Stack overflow but I couldn't get them to work.
I expect that any number larger than 0.05 to be modified.

You could use apply to loop through the columns:
Max90_NA <- as.xts(apply(Max90, 2, function(x) ifelse(x>0.05 , NA, x)))
head(Max90_NA)
                 AAPL        BAC       MSFT GOOGL       SWKS
2023-08-07 0.02310252 0.04421772 0.03979977    NA 0.03590555
2023-08-08 0.02310252 0.04421772 0.03979977    NA 0.03590555
2023-08-09 0.02310252 0.04421772 0.03979977    NA 0.03590555
2023-08-10 0.02310252 0.04421772 0.03979977    NA 0.03590555
2023-08-11 0.02310252 0.04421772 0.03979977    NA 0.03590555
2023-08-14 0.02310252 0.04421772 0.03979977    NA 0.03590555


Be careful with apply since If ‘X’ is not an array [...] ‘apply’ attempts to coerce [...] to an array via ‘as.matrix’ [...] or via ‘as.array’. Be sure to use as.xts to make it an xts object again.

Good spot! Edited with thanks.
